# Android Sqlite3 - column created by command line but not from my Android code

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on a project having an internal Sqlite database. I added a new table (**Table1**)
with 1 column (**column1**) via shell and via android inserting and deleting some new values in it.  I tried to add two new column **column2** and **column3** via command line and calling this via shell:

```
**PRAGMA table_info(Table1);**
```

I see that the creation of the two new column is correct because I get this output:

```
*0|column1|varchar(20)|1||1
1|column2|varchar(255)|1||0
2|column3|varchar(255)|1||0*
```

Fine.
The call to

```
**cursor.getColumnIndex("column1"));**
```

is continuing being ok but
passing another parameter as here:

```
**cursor.getColumnIndex("column2"));**
```

is returning **-1** such as this column has not been created. So same DB but difference between shell and android. Any tips to understand what is wrong?

Comment: How do you create the cursor?

Comment: Cursor cursor = db.query("Table1", columns, condition, null,
    null, null, null);
  while (cursor.moveToNext()) { ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any tips to understand what is wrong?

Problem may be related to db and cursor.

But as my recommendation if you want to make an upgrade of db(different version numbers) so it means perform some changes(add/remove/modify columns, relations, etc.) you should use for it [`onUpgrade()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade) method that is directly designated for purposes like yours or also there is a possibility to use classic `ALTER TABLE` clauses.

I don't recommend you to use `PRAGMA` via shell.

### Note:

For "assurance" try to perform in your application simple query:

```
String query = "pragma table_info(Table1)";
c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
      String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
      String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type"));
      Log.i("Information", name + " " + type);
   } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

By this you can find your where is problem. If it will show only one column, problem is db. If not, problem is cursor.

Answer (score 0):

It now works. I forgot to edit the parameter `columns` passed to this method that returns the `Cursor`.

```
 db.query();
```

The other answers were helpful in solving this issue.